Excel Pivot Table - Help Filtering
I am trying to find all my SKU share UPCs with another SKU. I have gotten everything into a pivot that that appears as in my image below. How do I filter it to only show UPCs with more than one SKU tied to it? Some of the UPCs have the same item code multiple times due to there being multiple stores, so just sorting by count doesn't help me.

I have been unable to try much of anything other than click around and find other ways to filter, but none of those options do what I need. I do not have the vocabulary regarding pivot tables to figure out what to search to find a tutorial.

It would be better to look at the source table.


If you have Excel 365 you can avoid using pivot tables and use one of the following formulas instead:
=LET(
    headers, A1:B1,
    data, FILTER(A2:B8, COUNTIF(A2:A8, A2:A8) > 1),
    VSTACK(headers, data)
)

or
=LET(
    uniqueUPCs, UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A8, COUNTIF(A2:A8, A2:A8) > 1)),
    counts, COUNTIF(A2:A8, uniqueUPCs),
    headers, {"UPC","Count of SKUs"},
    data, HSTACK(uniqueUPCs, counts),
    VSTACK(headers, data)
)

